# Why does the Redis cache client in ServiceStack return 0 instead of null for a non-existant key of an integer type?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis, servicestack

I am using the ServiceStack Cache Client with Redis to cache integers.

I am calling the Get method on a key I know does not exist like this:

```
int? count;
count = cachClient.Get<int>(myKey);
```

`count` always has a value of `0` after this call.

From the documentation, I am expecting the Get method to return null for a non-existant key.

Am I doing something wrong or understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: Haven't you said in the method call it needs to return type int, which isn't nullable (and so returns it's default value 0 instead). Try changing the second line to `count = cachClient.Get<int?>(myKey);` and see if it returns null then.

Comment: Well, that worked. Should have been obvious I suppose. Thanks! Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: At least it's not something more sinister! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said in the method call it needs to return type int, which isn't nullable (and so returns it's default value 0 instead). Try changing the second line to:

```
count = cachClient.Get<int?>(myKey);
```

and see if it returns null then.